# Magento 2.2 : How to add a background image in _extend.less?

Tags: magento2.2

I'm trying to add a background image to a div in the template **advertisement.phtml** of my custom page layout **home_custom.xml**.

For this, I have the following CSS in my **_extend.less** file:

```
div.outer {
    display: flex-inline;
    border: dotted;
    background: url('@{baseDir}images/advertisement.png');
}
```

Below is my custom theme's tree structure:

```
.
├── Magento_Theme
│   ├── layout
│   │   └── default.xml
│   ├── layouts.xml
│   ├── page_layout
│   │   └── home_custom.xml
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── advertisement.phtml
├── media
│   └── preview.png
├── registration.php
├── theme.xml
└── web
    ├── css
    │   └── source
    │       └── _extend.less
    └── images
        ├── advertisement.png
        └── logo.svg
```

However, I see the dotted border, but not the background image. How should I fix this issue ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem came from AdBlock, the name of my picture contained the word `advertisement`, this is why the image was blocked.

Answer (score 2):

Follow code:

```
div.outer {
    display: flex-inline;
    border: dotted;
    background: url('../images/advertisement.png');
}
```

Your `extend.less` by compiling the above code arrives in `styles-l.css` and `styles-m.css` files in `/pub/static/frontend/Magento/Theme/en_GB/css` and the image `advertisement.png` is in `/pub/static/frontend/Magento/Theme/en_GB/images`, so you must exit the `css` folder and enter the `images` folder, both of which are at the same level.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: You must run command in terminal: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Magento/Theme`

Comment: It still doesn't work after deploying static content, do I need to declare the image file somewhere first ?